# How do I embed a Vimeo video in HTML?

Tags: html, embed, vimeo

In HTML, you use the `<iframe src="https://youtube.com/embed/videoId>` element to embed a YouTube video. However, how am I embed Vimeo videos using the `<iframe>` element?

Comment: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224969968-Embedding-videos-overview

Comment: All the necessary information is there in [developer.vimeo.com](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed/videos)..Please check it..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are signed in on Vimeo, an go to your video settings, there should be an menu "Embed". Click this item and you will get various embedding options.

At the right side of the window (below your profile icon) there will be a button `Embed code`. Clicking this will give you the Embed code. Here is an example it generated for me. I removed my video number though.

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/**yourvideonumberhere**" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And of course, embedding should be allowed for the video in the settings.

Answer (score 6):

```
<iframe width="100%" height="550" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/403530213" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Example `iframe` is above. You should also open embed options from vimeo console and be sure if it is public. If not you should use API for Vimeo with keys.

https://jsfiddle.net/c1x40sLp/

Answer (score 1):

Simply click on the share button icon from the list of the available icons at the top-right, then a modal will pop up with an option for you to share video with a link url or embed. Simply copy the embed code snippet and paste on your html file.

Comment: This was short and sweet!